# managing ssh public keys on github organizations repositories

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys

I was wondering if anyone has a good, clean, safe way to manage github Organization repository access on their servers?

It seems that you can only attach pub keys to your personal account and cannot restrict access solely to an organization.

We've got a beta server where we put multiple projects so deploy keys, because they need to be unique, aren't ideal. It would be nice to give global access to the organization, but I don't want to give the server, which we have freelancers on, full access to my personal account (The server gets access to the organization, which is good, but also to my personal projects and every other organization I belong to, which is bad).

The two workarounds that I see is to either set up a dummy github user to go through, which seems stupid, or to enable ssh agent forwarding, which feels like a security risk (I'm not the best server-admin).

A friend suggested setting up the server as a remote to push to, but it seems like a band-aid solution.

I would like to think there's an easier way to set up access for an organization's repo as I would think it would be a fundamental need for everyone.

I'm all ears if anyone would like to share something that has/is working for their github organization.

I'll probably just bite the bullet and create a dummy github user and call it a day, I need to get work done.

Comment: Why do you think agent forwarding is a security risk?  Do you not understand how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to the answer from sergey_mo (and as a direct answer Michał Szajbe's final question) is to create multiple ssh keys as documented by chalien on githib:

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Old answer, I know … But here's [a working link](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) (I'm assuming that's the original document/info linked to in above answer).

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why adding a dummy-account is so bad for automatic deployment, as long as you run your own beta-server as a staging area before pushing to GitHub. That is, if you want the betacode to be private.

The usual GitHub-way would be to add all the collaborators and simply have a stable project and a beta fork. You'd automatically pull the current beta version to your beta server for testing (no ssh key needed there) and if your tests succeed, you pull in the merges from the beta fork to the stable project.

Comment: I guess it's not the worst thing in the world, I was just hoping to be able to manage organization access with one account without having to juggle log-ins like I used to. It kind of makes sense though since organizations aren't users. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Problem is, if you use dummy accounts in any DVCS, you will not able to blame or annotate / who did what, which comes in very handy is one of the accounts get's hacked and you don't have to send new keys to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Small note about CI:
For instance, if you use Jenkins and you need it to access more then 1 project you will need to:
1. add public key to one github user account 
2. add this user as Owner (to access all projects) or as a Collaborator in every project.

Many public keys  for one system user will not work because GitHub will find first matched deploy key and will send back error like **"ERROR: Permission to user/repo2 denied to user/repo1"**

http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that you can only attach pub keys to your personal account and cannot restrict access solely to an organization.

Actually, in March 2023, you can:

> ### [SSH Certificate requirement update](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-16-ssh-certificate-requirement-update) (Mar. 2023)
>
> The "Require SSH certificates" policy now allows GitHub apps to call Git APIs using a user-to-server token, bringing them up to parity with OAuth app support.
>
> The SSH certificate requirement mandates that users in your organization call Git APIs using an SSH certificate issued by your organization, in place of their own SSH key or a PAT.
>
> To support automation, it has an exception in place for OAuth apps and GitHub app server-to-server tokens, which allows applications you've approved to call Git APIs for your organization.
>
> With this change, we are extending that exception to GitHub app user-to-server tokens, for when a user has signed in to a GitHub app that's installed in your organization.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1666363/225112716-0e0c0c73-ce3b-4b49-a1fe-46fdb9395a39.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of the SSH Certificate requirement checkbox]
>
> This change also applies when the enterprise-level setting requires SSH certificates across all organizations in the enterprise.
>
> To learn more, see:
>
> - ["Managing your organization's SSH certificate authorities"](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-git-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/managing-your-organizations-ssh-certificate-authorities#adding-an-ssh-certificate-authority) or
> - ["Managing SSH certificate authorities for your enterprise"](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/policies/enforcing-policies-for-your-enterprise/enforcing-policies-for-security-settings-in-your-enterprise#managing-ssh-certificate-authorities-for-your-enterprise).

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by having your applications run by different users (one user per application). I mean server users, not github users. It's a good practice anyway on multi-app servers.

Each user then has it's own ssh keypair, so you have many unique deploy keys (one per github repo).

I use this approach whenever possible. However there are situations when more than one app is run by a single user and it probably can't be done with github's deploy keys. I'm also looking for a good solution to such cases.