# How to connect to an organization's guthub repository using ssh key using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019, ssh-keys

I prefer to using ssh keys and there is a lot to learn for me always!
My current challenge is:
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I have my organization's private repositories in guthub under the organization's name.
When i try to connect to one of the repositories under the name of my organization, i am getting this error:

```
permission denied (publickey)
```

I have generated ssh keys as follows:

```
id_rsa_personal@gmail
id_rsa_work_alias@organization
```

I also have a config file in `~/.ssh/config` with contents as below:

```
#github personal
Host personal
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal@gmail

#github work
Host work
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work_alias@organization
```

In my visual studio 2019, under `MenuBar-> Git-> Manage Remotes` is setup to use `ssh` for `fetch` and `push`

[image]

Here is what my github dashboard looks like

[image]

As you can see, it has two entries one for my `work alias` and one for my `organization`

I mostly work on repositories under the Organization.

But while adding the `ssh key` contents to github, i added so under my `work alias` account

[image]

Now when i try to do a fetch from Visual Studio 2019, i get the error

```
permission denied (publickey)
```

Examining the `Your Organizations` menu option, i do not see a `settings` option.

[image]

So, in my case, should i be configuring visual studio 2019 to be using https:// to perform git operations? please clarify

Comment: Note, that your ~/.ssh/config entries only will apply when you try to connect to SSH servers you address as `personal` or `work`.
Thus the Git URL would have to be: `git@work:Organization/api-1.git`

Answer (score 0):

March 2023: [**SSH Certificate requirement update**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762843/6309)

> The "Require SSH certificates" policy now allows GitHub apps to call Git APIs using a user-to-server token, bringing them up to parity with OAuth app support.

---

2021: To add to [sborsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404368/sborsky)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911053/how-to-connect-to-an-organizations-guthub-repository-using-ssh-key-using-visual#comment121789448_68911053), assuming everything is running with the current user (the one with `~/.ssh/config`), the actual URL to use would be:

```
work:Organization/api-1.git
```

No need to repeat the user, which is already specified in `~/.ssh/config`

Check first if it works with:

```
ssh -Tv work
```

You should see an error message, unless:

- your account is not part of the organization
- and/or you have not properly added the public key to your GitHub account.